# Saving a file in Java

Tags: java, file, file-io

I have a String that holds a path to a file.  I want the users to be able to select a path and filename with a file chooser and have the program save the file given in the String variable to a location of their choice.  What is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 5):

Read the [JFileChooser tutorial](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/uiswing/components/filechooser.html).

Answer (score 3):

JFileChooser can provide the UI for selecting a file. See the [Javadoc](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JFileChooser.html) for documentation and example code.

You may then save the string to a file like this:

```
String stringToSave = "this will be saved...";
// set up the jfilechooser...
//
int returnVal = chooser.showSaveDialog(parent);
if(returnVal == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
    File file = chooser.getSelectedFile();
    try {
        PrintStream ps = new PrintStream(file);
        ps.print(stringToSave);
        ps.close();
    } catch (IOException ioe) {
        // ... handle errors!
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

use JFileChooser